# DOM - Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8 with RemoveChild

Tags: php, javascript, html, removechild

I need to remove a child added with PHP. When I try to use removeChild, Chrome throws this:

```
Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8
```

Here is the code I am using to delete the element:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].removeChild(document.getElementById("e"+eid));
```

And here is the code that defines the element:

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
<tr id='e0'>
   <td>
      gs
   </td>
   <td>
     <a href='#' onclick='showpm(0); return false;'>
       Open
     </a>
   </td>
   <td>
     <a href='#' onclick='delpm(7, 0); return false;'>
       Delete
     </a>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrome adds a `tbody` tag to your table, so you'll have to remove the child of that element, or

```
var tr = document.getElementById("e"+eid);
tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be better using the deleteRow() method of the table, see the examples [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_deleterow.asp)